# Normalizing two independent weights in order to produce output between 0 and 1

Tags: normal-distribution, density-function, bernoulli-distribution

I have two scores, alpha and beta, ranging both between 0 and 1.

I want to weight these with *weight_one, weight_two* in order to favour one of these scores over the other.

Then, afterwards, I want to return a normalised score again between 0 and 1 which is produced with regard to both scores. Is this possible?

How could I arrange this so that:

```
if: alpha = 1 AND beta = 1 THEN output = 1 (no matter what weights)
else: output = [0,1] always, yet weights favour either alpha or beta more.
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: What is your question, exactly?  After all, after you have selected the weights (and that's a subjective matter which we cannot address here), the weighted combinations of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are just numbers and they will lie within some finite range that you can then easily normalize to the interval $[0,1]$ with a linear transformation (as described in many other threads).

Comment: Hey Sycorax! Yes, I belief I do. I don't understand why I didn't thought of that, now that it seems so logical. Thank you though. It seems like it really works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a convex combination. If $\alpha \in[0,1]$ and $\beta \in [0,1]$, then the convex combination yields
$$
0 \le \lambda\alpha + (1-\lambda)\beta \le 1
$$

for any $\lambda \in[0,1]$.